# the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used while trying to use if case

Tags: r, twitter

I have a csv fie as:

```
score   text
```

1   0   RT @RealJackEdwards: (2 of) a solution. 7 st yrs in playoffs, a Cup, a Final, a Prez Trophy. Yup, Boychuk trade a disaster; Bottom 6 fwds râ€¦

I need to write all the tweets with negative score to a different file. I am trying to use if statement as:

```
if(stat$score < 0 )
```

write.csv(stat$text, file=paste('negtweetscore.csv'), row.names=TRUE)

But after running this code i am getting the following error message:

> In if (stat$score < 0) write.csv(stat$text, file = paste("negtweetscore.csv"),  :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Obviously `stat$score` is a vector with a length greater than 1, hence R is complaining about that.  Change your logic to use a scalar in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to subset your `data.frame` properly:

```
  write.csv(stat$text[stat$score<0], file=paste('negtweetscore.csv'), row.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hey Nicola, Thanks for your help. It is now working. If i have to add the score as well within this negtweetscore file. How can i do that